# return mongodb document as text in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm working on a project in pymongo and flask where I have a movies database and I use an endpoint to find a specific movie by title . If the movie exists I want to return all of the specific movie's fields (. ex. movie = {"title" : "Hobbit" , "year" :2013} ) as plain html text . However I am a beginner and I cannot manage to return the fields with my code :

```
 @app.route('/findmoviebytitle' ,methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
 def find_movie_by_title():
        if request.method =='POST':
              movie = movies.find_one({"title":request.form['title']})
              if movie != None: //if movie exists
                    movie = {'_id': str(movie['_id']) , 'Title' : movie['title'] , 
                   'Actors' : movie['actors'] , 'year' : movie , 'plot':movie['plot'] }
                    return ''' {% for key, value in movie.items() %} //return movie fields
                              {{ value.item }} 
                            {% endfor %}  '''
        return render_template('movie-title.html') //this is the page where I submit a movie title
```

I would appreciate your help with this task . Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you want to return it as text?

Comment: @ngShravil.py as a text in a web page lets say you have a movie called hobbit published in 2013 I want to display these stats in a web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display in a web page, converting to string is not required. It will be unnecessary work. Here you are doing just `find_one()`, but in cases where you have to fetch many records, then converting to string will eat up lots of resource.

You need to do the following changes:

**app.py**

```py
from flask import render_template # Import this, you you have not imported
@app.route('/findmoviebytitle' ,methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
def find_movie_by_title():
       if request.method =='POST':
             movie = movies.find_one({"title":request.form['title']})
             if movie != None:
                   return render_template('movie-details.html', movie=movie)
       return render_template('movie-title.html')
```

**movie-details.html**

```html
{% for key, value in movie.items() %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if you have too many records don't you iterate through a cursor ?then the movie-details.html will have the same code ?

Comment: Nope. In the current scenario, we are doing `find_one`, this will return only one document, so in the `html` page we will be only iterating through the items of that document. In the new scenario, we will be having many documents, for each document we need to display the items. So, we will be having two loops. First loop, for the documents and second loop, for the items of each document. I will leave it to you, for learning purpose. If you get stuck, let me know.

Comment: I found it . Thank you very much . You have helped me again before